# What is the correct way to bind template into html?

Tags: html, web

//here is the javascript to bind the template

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var template=document.getElementById("#template");
        var clone=document.importNode(template.content,true);
        var host=document.getElementById("#host");
        host.appendChild(clone);
    </script>
```

//this is the template.. i tried using 'template' tag too

```
 <script typ="text/template" id="template">

        <p>from the template</p>

    </script>
```

//template host in html DOM

```
 <div id="host">
    <p>inside the host</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it work with this approach:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var template=document.getElementById("template");
            var host=document.getElementById("host");
            host.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
    </script>
```

or you can change `host.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;` for `host.innerHTML += template.innerHTML;` if you want to append the content of your template to your `host`.

You can watch it working in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noy5m5dd/)